# Is one anti-malware software enough?

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, anti-virus, anti-malware, malwarebytes

I only have Malwarebytes Premium (version 2.2.0....) installed on my Windows 8.1 computer.  I understand that there are different varieties of malware, like viruses, trojans, worms, hijackers, etc., and different anti-malware software is often labelled differently in relation to the kinds of threats they protect against.

Is Malwarebytes Premium a "comprehensive" program, in terms of being in the class of applications that protect against the full range of malware types, or is it focused on particular types of malware, which would imply the need to either supplement it with additional applications to protect against the other threats or switch to a more comprehensive program?

Comment: For your second question see [What's the difference between "anti-virus", "anti-malware" and "anti-spyware" tools?](https://superuser.com/q/695501)

Comment: Your first question is off-topic (opinion based). Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://superuser.com/help/dont-ask).

Comment: What i want to ask is: Do i need an anti-virus or not? I will update my question. Thanks, David.

Comment: Your edited question is **still opinion based**. Did you read the links I gave you?

Answer (score 1):

One virusscanner is enough for your PC. When you install multiple virusscanners is there the possibility that they are going to fight each other (then they both doesnt work).

Comment: True, the software's may be incompatible. But not all anti-virus are incompatible (i think Avira is). Not all anti-virus have top-notch security.

Comment: You are right, not all antivirus is incompatible. But i think you really dont need another antivirus. Malwarebytes Premium is fine for you! *mpboom